# Frege trace not printing

Tags: haskell, trace, stderr, frege

As the title says, for some reason, messages passed to the `trace` (well, a variant of which) function don't show up properly when debugging functions. Simply flushing stdout/stderr doesn't seem to do anything, either.

```
-- Makes it more like Haskell's trace
debug :: String -> α -> α
debug msg f = const f $ trace msg

-- dummy function
polyA :: (Num α) => α
polyA = debug "polyA\n" 0

-- another dummy function
polyB :: (Num α) => α
polyB = debug "polyB\n" polyA

main :: IO ()
main = do println (polyB :: Int    )
          println (polyB :: Int    )
          println (polyB :: Integer)
```

Output is just

```
0
0
```

with nothing visible in stderr (normally represented by red text in Eclipse's console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `const` doesn't use the second argument, `trace` doesn't get invoked. You could use `seq` or pattern match.

If you change the `debug` function to this:

```
debug msg f = trace msg `seq` f
```

or to this:

```
debug msg f | trace msg = undefined
            | otherwise = f
```

It still won't print anything due to flushing so if you change the `main` to flush `stderr`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do println (polyB :: Int    )
          println (polyB :: Int    )
          println (polyB :: Integer)
          stderr.flush
```

It would work and it prints all the debug messages at the end:

```
frege> main
0
0
0
polyA
polyB
polyA
polyB
polyA
polyB
()
```

As Ingo mentioned, we could also use `traceLn` to have it flushed automatically when the function is called.

Comment: One could also use `traceLn` to make it print in "real time"

Answer (score 2):

I changed `debug` to:

```
debug :: String -> α -> α
debug msg f = if trace msg then f else f
```

and got output emitted onto stderr.